# CordovaBrowser_NavigationFailed when connect to facebook

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth

I am using ng-cordova-oauth plugin (https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oaut) to connect with Facebook and Google plus. It works fine with android but in WP8 I get this error.

```
CordovaBrowser_NavigationFailed :: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={client-id}&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&response_type=token&scope=email,user_friends
```